# Use guard-let to modify possibly nil expression before assigning variable

Tags: swift, swift2

I wish to use `guard-let` to assign a variable to an expression, but I want to modify the expression before assigning. If the expression is `nil`, then the `else` block should be entered, otherwise the variable should be assigned to `f(expression)`. Here is an example of what I would like to do:

```
let arr: [Int] = []
// Do stuff, maybe add elements to arr
guard let x = abs(arr.first) else { return } // Syntax error
// If arr was nonempty, then we want x = abs(arr.first!)
```

But Swift does not allow this syntax because `abs` requires a non-optional argument, and `arr.first` is optional. So is there any way to evaluate `arr.first`, and then if it is not `nil` to assign `abs(arr.first!)` to `x`? I know that I could do this with `if-let` or by using two variables (one from the `guard-let` and then one that gets assigned to the absolute value of that variable). But `guard-let` seems like the tool for the job, if only there were some way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let arr:[Int] = [-1,1,3,-9]
guard let x = arr.first.flatMap({ $0 < 0 ? -$0: $0 }) else { return }
    // ...
```

or (UPDATE based on dfri's notes)

```
// ....
let arr:[Int] = [-1,1,3,-9]
guard let x = arr.first.map(abs) else { return }
```

Comment: Hmm, this might be the best answer... seems like Swift's built in way to make this work and exactly answers what I was looking for. Any reason you don't just `flatMap { abs($0) }` though?

Comment: @James abs is not part of swift language ... no other reason. i like 'pure' swift solution, if available

Comment: Oh, you have to import Foundation to use it? I guess I do that for every file anyway, so it's no big deal to me. To each his own.

Comment: @James so use it as guard let x = arr.first.flatMap (abs) else { return }

Comment: A function as a first class citizen is nicer than a closure; good edit.

Comment: @user3441734 This is really neat, didn't think of using the mapping (`.map`/`.flatMap`) methods on `Optional`, +1! Note though, that you needn't necessarily use `.flatMap` here; `.map` suffices as your mapping closures does not possibly return `nil` (the only difference between the two for `Optional`:s is that `.flatMap` allows `nil`-returning closure, as closure return type is optional itself). So in the sense of "never doing anything more than what is necessary", I'd personally probably prefer using the somewhat more suitable (in this case) `.map` over `.flatMap` above.

Comment: Also note that, as far as I know, [`abs` is a native global Swift function](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/func/abs/) (see also [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_AbsoluteValuable_Protocol/index.html)), so no need for importing `Foundation` in your second example above.

Comment: @dfri and yes,"never doing anything more than what is necessary" is really good idea, so using map there is nice idea!

Answer (score 2):

I think the cleanest and simplest solution would be like this:

```
guard let first = arr.first else { return }
let x = abs(first)
```

Now the calculation `abs(first)` is only reached if `arr.first != nil`.

Comment: You are right. Sorry! That's what I get for answering on my phone without compiling. I fixed my answer accordingly.

Comment: I deleted my obsolete comment.

Answer (score 2):

**`Optional(Some<Int>) -> Int -> Optional<abs(Some<Int)> -> Int` ... meh**

You could do a dirty `guard let ..., let ... else` fix as follows (forcing the binded certainly-not-`nil` value of `x` to become an optional which you subsequently immediately unwrap and bind to `xAbs`)

```
func foo() {
    let arr: [Int] = [-1, 2, -3, 4]

    guard let x = arr.first,
          let xAbs = Optional(abs(xAbs)) else { return }
    print(xAbs, xAbs.dynamicType)
}

foo() // 1 Int
```

This doesn't look very pretty however, and I would, personally, prefer adding an `Int` extension and make use of optional chaining, as I will cover next.

**Instead: use extensions and optional chaining**

Unless you explicitly need to store `x` as well as `xAbs`, an alternative and more Swifty approach is to use optional chaining in combination with a simple extension to `Int`:

```
extension Int {
    var absValue: Int { return abs(self) }
}

func foo() {
    let arr: [Int] = [-1, 2, -3, 4]

    guard let xAbs = arr.first?.absValue else { return }
    print(xAbs, xAbs.dynamicType)
}

foo() // 1 Int
```

Since `arr.first` is an optional `Int` variable, you can implement whatever method/computed property you wish onto `self` as an extension to `Int`, and access that method/property using optional chaining `arr.first?.someMethod()`/`arr.first?.someProperty` (as `.absValue` above).

**Or, simply modify your `arr.first` (unwrapped) value after the `guard let ... else` block**

I see no reason, however (other than the technical discussion) not to introduce an additional immutable holding the absolute value of `x`. This will also increase code readability, at least w.r.t. to the dirty `guard let ..., let ... else` fix above.

```
// ...

guard let x = arr.first else { return }
let xAbs = abs(x)
```

Or, if you find it acceptable for your `xAbs` property to be mutable, out of a theoretical perspective your *could* remove the middle-man immutable by using a `guard var ...` block rather than `guard let ...`

```
guard var xAbs = arr.first else { return }
xAbs = abs(xAbs)
```

This should probably only be used, however, if `xAbs` is to be mutated again (i.e., use immutables whenever you really don't need mutables, and never the other way around).

Comment: I like the `absValue` approach. Now that I think about it, it seems like they should have implemented `absValue` as a computed property by default. The static `abs` function is a clunky holdover from C.

Answer (score 2):

What you want can be achieved using `case let`.

```
let arr: [Int] = [1,2,3,4]
guard let first = arr.first, case let absolute = abs(first) else { return }
// use `absolute`
```